# Grab windows console output into a file (not redirection, no screen shots)

Tags: cmd.exe, console, cut-and-paste, clink

(Not redirection) I want to grab and save ALL the windows cmd console (win7) text into a file, without using the mouse. I need the text for doing command completion, instead of copy/pasting parts of words from the console. This is on win7 with cmd + clink / cygwin bash / vim.

So far I have

```
[Alt-Space][S select-all][Enter to copy text] 
vi [enter] [Shift-paste]
   then do completion inside vim, 
   copy words to clipboard
   :q!
[paste into cmd]
```

Comment: Unclear. Do you want clink/bash do *special* word completion for you? Do you understand that you have to write at least some script for that?

Comment: I need a program that can grab the console text into a file, then I could write some (bash readline completion script). Clink doesn't  have scripts, but clink does completion better than bash without messing the wrapped lines.

Comment: ConEmu may log console output continuously. Properly escape your PS1 to have proper wrapped lines I bash. Clink is scriptable by design, it's Lua.

Comment: Maximus, thanks for the suggestion, I have conEmu, I will look into it. I haven't used Lua.